# My Baofeng radio can transmit and hit a repeater 50 miles away but it isn't receiving

Tags: antenna, baofeng

My radio won't receive. Help? It literally went dead and I still have the rubber duck antenna

Comment: that's a bit of a vague description. I'm afraid "won't receive" isn't a monocausal thing. Battery OK? Do leds light up? Baofeng is a company, not a single device (they have dozens), so what are we talking about? What does "literally dead" mean (aside from giving me the opportunity to say that *literally* it was never alive)?

Comment: @Nvictoro5R I voted to reject your edit to the question.  It sounds like you're having the same problem as the original poster (OP), and you're trying to revive the question.  Kudos to you for doing your homework and finding a question that applies to your situation.  The problem is that if we voted to accept your edit, then you'd be "putting words into the OP's mouth".  The thing to do is to make a new question, so please do that and then we can help you there!

Answer (score 2):

If your radio can't receive unless you hold the MONI button it can mean your squelch is set too tight.  Or, it means you can't hear static unless you hold MONI.  If it is brand new out of the box I think maybe you mean the latter.

But let's take it a step at a time.

Ideally you don't want to hear static, but you do want to hear signals when they are present.

Your post is vague but I presume that if you let go of MONI then it will transmit.  That is normal behavior.

So first, check your squelch setting.  The best way to find it is to go through the menu.  On handhelds, there is a menu button and you will find it in there.  Also on handhelds it is a secondary function of the 0 (zero) button.  But my suggestion is to stick with the menu first, and get to know what all you can find in there before using the function keys (which are different by model).

Once you find squelch, try different settings - 0 should make it act as if you were holding the MONI key - no squelch.  2 or 3 should be enough to quiet it down yet allow signals through.  4 or 5 will only let strong signals through.

Set it one step above where you hear static all the time - that will allow it to be at its most sensitive yet still have the static squelch function.

**Please allow me to suggest a couple of edits to your question:**

**Change your title to "My Baofeng UV-5R V2+ radio can't hear anything unless I hold the MONI button"**

**In your text, you can describe how you can hear things with MONI pressed but can't transmit unless you let go of MONI.  Mentioning that you are using the rubber duck indicates both that you have a handheld and that you might wonder if a better antenna would fix the problem, etc., etc.  Whatever you think is relevant to your question**

(Of course, use the model number of your actual radio)

Then upvote my answer.

Accepting my answer is very helpful, too, if it turns out it is correct and helpful.

Please leave a comment on my answer describing how you made it work so others might find this question and get the answer more easily.

After you do that I'll check your tags to make sure it is even easier for others to find by searching.  I'll leave you a comment so you know when that is done - so you can see how to use them in the future.

Welcome to ham.stackexchange!